# How to make changes in widget in parent activity based on the logic written in fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

As an exercise i am writing a simple Ebook reader app. This has only 1 Main Activity with 3 widgets on it, 2 buttons (Previous, Next) and one Fragment container(I have used Frame Layout). All pages are different fragments that I have created that will go inside the container, and these fragments have only 1 scrollable text view that will only display text. when "next" button is pressed it should go to page2(fragment2) and when previous is pressed it should go back(previous fragment).

My problem is I don't want the "previous" button to show up on the initial screen (page1) and similarly the "next" button should not be observed on the last page.

The approach i tried was, in my fragment1(page1) class, i wrote an if condition like,

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup 
container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragmentpage1,container,false);

    textView1=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.tview);
    **View listView = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.previous);**
    textView1.setText(R.string.page1);

    if (textView1.isEnabled()){

        listView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }
    return view;
}
```

I am checking if textview1(the first fragment) is present or not , if yes then hide the previous button on the Main Activity. This works but it completely hides the previous button even when i go to page2. I tried all possible "is" options but none of them are giving me the results I want.

One workaround that i found was to add "setvisibility" of previous button to all fragments, so on fragment1 it is invisible and then on fragment2 i changed that to visible. But that becomes lengthy if there are 100s of fragments(pages).

Please provide me with a simple solution, I am new to Android.

Below is my Main Activity code:(Do let me know if any changes needs to be done to make code more clean)

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

```
Fragment fragment;
FragmentManager fm=getSupportFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction ft;


private static Button next;
private static Button previous;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    next=(Button)findViewById(R.id.next);
    previous=(Button)findViewById(R.id.previous);

    create();

  }

  public void create(){

      fragment= new FragmentPage1();
      ft=  fm.beginTransaction();
      ft.add(container,fragment);
      ft.commit();
   }

   public void next(View view){

        fragment= new FragmentPage2();

           ft=  fm.beginTransaction();
           ft.replace(container,fragment);
           ft.commit();
```

}
}

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try to use the getItem() method in FragmentPagerAdapter class.
Try to disable or enable your buttons using the switch case. Hope this can help =)